# NopCommerce deployment error on azure

Tags: azure, nopcommerce

Recently launched portal for azure https://portal.azure.com has Gallery feature hosting ready made web applications. I tried installing nopAzure on it. But it is giving me error "Error creating nopCommerce".

In the events it shows Failed status for operation "Update deploymnet". Any idea about how to resolve this issue?

I tried using East Asia instance for my website and database.